# 2 Separate Machines, 2 Static IP Address. No connection Outside ISP Network

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, centos, port

I have two separate physical machines. The first one is running CentOS 6.6 x86_64, and the second is running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. (also 64-bit)

Here's the issue. Both servers have a direct connection to the internet with a public IP address, and a LAN connection to a "server network".

I have 29 static IP addresses available from my ISP, and these systems are accessible from those 29 IP addresses, but not outside that network.

For example, if I remove my Android smart phone from WiFi, and type in the public IP of each server, I get a generic "Could not load website" page from my browser. But if I connect to my WiFi and load the public address, it works as it is supposed to. It will even resolve the websites hosted on the server.

Both servers have CSF firewall installed, and running, and ports 20, 21, 22, 25, 53, 80, 110, 143, 443, 465, 587, 993, 995, and 10000 are open as far as both servers are concerned.

Here's the steps I've taken so far.

> - I can telnet the ports on each server from the local network (server lan).
> - I have also disabled the firewall to see if maybe that was causing it. (It wasn't)
> - I disabled any and all support for IPv6 on both servers (forum post said it might help).
> - Changed DNS Servers (used Google Public, ISP Public, FreeDNS, etc)
> - Called ISP (not an issue with the network or it'd be affecting all IP's)

Now to be clear. These two servers are the only two servers that seem to be having this issue. I have about 14 other servers using these IP addresses and they are all functioning fine.

Here is a look at the ifcfg-eth0 file on the CentOS Machine

```
DEVICE=eth0
GATEWAY=71.xxx.xxx.1
BOOTPROTO=none
HWADDR=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR=71.xxx.xxx.61
NETWORK=71.xxx.xxx.0
ONBOOT=yes
ARPCHECK=no
NETWORKING_IPV6=no
IPV6INIT=no
```

Here is the /etc/sysconfig/network file from the CentOS machine

```
NETWORKING=yes
NETWORKING_IPv6=no
GATEWAY=71.xxx.xxx.1
HOSTNAME=ns1
```

Here is

> route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
71.xxx.xxx.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         71.xxx.xxx.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

It's probably something simple that I'm just not seeing. If I wasn't already balding, I'd be pulling my hair out right now.

The Ubuntu machine gives the same results from the tests above, except the IP ends in 62, rather than 61, and Ubuntu's hostname is ns2.

**Note:** If I left something out that you need to see, please simply let me know and I'll update this post.

Here's an MXToolbox Scan

[image]

I've omitted the IP Addresses because they are hosting servers.

Comment: @Kevin Maguire. I have checked with our Internet Service Provider and confirmed that indeed our Sub Net for our Public IP Addresses is 255.255.255.0, I even double checked all of the supplied information. It's all correct.

Comment: Clarification request: "I have 29 static IP addresses" Do you mean you have **32** IPs available (with one for router, one for broadcast and one for the network, leaving 29 **useable** IPs?).   (That would also imply 6 bits for hosts, and a netmask of 11111111.1111111.11111111.11000000 aka 255.255.255.192 aka /26).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be closed. I noticed that for some reason we were limited to only using 13 of our IP addresses (we have 29), the ISP discovered a massive error in the network. We have maintenance scheduled Tuesday.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure netmask is 255.255.255.0?

You got 29 addresses from ISP - suggests (maybe) otherwsise.

KM

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).